# Why is this python generator function running correctly only once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

This is almost certainly a result of my ignorance of how generators work, but I am completely lost.

If I interactively create the following generator:

```
def neighborhood(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    prev = None
    item = next(iterator) 
    for post in iterator:
        yield (prev,item,post)
        prev = item
        item = post
    yield (prev,item,None)
```

and then test it like:

```
for prev,item,next in neighborhood([1,2,3,4,5]):
print(prev, item, next)
```

It produces:

```
None 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 None
```

as expected. If I run it again, or try to redefine it in any way, I get a

> 'NoneType' object is not callable"

error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you did

```
for prev,item,next in ...
#             ^^^^
```

you shadowed the built-in `next` function. The next time you try to use your generator, it fails because it gets your `next` variable instead of the function it needed.

Comment: Dang it. Yes. So dumb.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're using a variable named `next` in your test code. Use a name that doesn't shadow the built-in function `next`.